# What will be the current i(0) in this problem?

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

I am doing b) and I am just wondering whether i(0) will be v_in(0)/R. Do I use 5 V or 2 V or is it 0?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: I believe it's asking you do do one at a time (it's basically looking for two more answers).

Answer (score 1):

There is a series inductor in there so you know that the current cannot change instantaneously at the instant t=0, it will be the same as the current was just an instant earlier.

Answer (score 1):

i(0) = 0 A, before t=0 the capacitor is charged, therefore the current before that time is zero. And since the coil doesn't like current changes, the current is still zero, in that precise time. Beginning to have current in t>0.

Answer (score 0):

At t=0 we will have zero current because of the inductor. Reason behind 0 current is that changing the voltage across the inductor will change the electric field across the inductor. This change in electric field will cause the changing magnetic field. That changing magnetic field will cause the voltage in the inductor according to faradays law and that induced voltage in the inductor will have the voltage polarity equal and opposite to the source voltage according to lenz law. Thats why the moment voltage changes in inductor it will face equal and opposite voltage from the inductor so there will be no current at t=0